# Hyperparameter optimisation over entire range or shorter range of training episodes in Deep Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, hyperparameter-optimization

I am optimising hyperparameters for my deep reinforcement learning project (using PPO2, DQN and A2C) and was wondering:

Should I find the optimum hyperparameters to get maximum reward from training over my entire range of training (e.g. 50 million steps) or can I optimise over less time (e.g. 1 million steps)?

What is the conventional approach and why?

Comment: There is no conventional approach. It's a happy event if RL method converge at all, hyperparameter optimization is a luxury few can afford. If computational resources permit better to do it over a longer period, RL methods have notoriously high variance.